# CSS - clear styles for element

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using the `tinymce` `wysiwyg` for creating some nice looking instructions for my website.
I simply save the html generated code into my database, and display that html on a page.

Since my website has it's own stylesheets loaded, some things tend to show up according to what the styles dictate (like `<ul>`, `<li>`, or `<p>` tags)

If any of those tags are generated from `tinymce`, my site's stylesheets will style them.

Shot in the dark - Is there a style that makes a browser ignore all styles that reside inside a specific element?

For visual aid, here is a snapshot of the `tinymce` and what I'm making:
[image: TinyMce]

And here is a snapshot of the displayed html, on my site:

[image: Result of TinyMce]

(this html resides inside  `<div id="tinymce_html"><?php echo $tinymce_html; ?></div>`)

Here's the css that's affecting it (site-wide), inside the main.css stylesheet

```
ol, ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Btw, I'm only giving an example of just the result for the `<ul>` tags.  I'm sure I'll run into plenty more tags.  (hence my original question - "is there a style that makes a browser ignore all styles that reside in a specific element?")

What I don't want to do is create an entirely new style sheet for anything related to `tinymce`, or other `html` I'd like to display without being affected by any site styles.

Comment: What you're describing is a bit of a [CSS code smell](http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/); you should really have a look at making your existing style sheets be *less* generic (i.e. not applying styles to all `ol` elements, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Use always a "reset css" before start new project!

Take a look at [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Copy paste this style above your code and start from this. It reset all your elements.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that reset sheet above will add some confusion. Tiny uses strong to make selection bold, also it uses em to make selection italic. So one must define these two (at least) somewhere else in some other stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to apply a css reset stylesheet.
Have a look [here](http://www.cssreset.com/) and take the one that seems the most applicable to you.

You will have to add this css to the editor using the [custom_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) tinymce config option.